# bind a click event to a div block generated on the fly using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which completely created on the fly when the page is loaded and this div is visible to the user and in firebug but when i view the page source its not available.. the content within the div changes dynamically.

im trying to bind a click event to it so when someone clicks on that div to alert a message..

i have go through almost all the suggestions but none of them work

my dynamic div

```
<div class="mootoo drive form2">Hello this a mootoo test</div>
```

Tested JQuery functions

```
$(document).on('click', ".mootoo", function() {
      alert("clicked");
});


 $('.mootoo').on('click',function() { 
  alert("clicked");
    });


 $('.mootoo').live('click',function() { 
  alert("clicked");
    });
```

Can someone please tell me what am i doing wrong?

---

actually i cant find the JQ code where it generates the div But im having the exact same problem with this

http://jsfiddle.net/g1sqrxg6/3/

if you see when i click it doesnt alert "chosen-choices" is the dynamically created class..

in that case i when a user selects and or clicks on that div or box i need to put an alert

Comment: possible duplicate of [Click event doesn't work on dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6658752/click-event-doesnt-work-on-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: do you have jQuery loaded to your page? because first one surely work.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for the issue. Regarding your dynamic content not visible in page source, page source will show only the static content.

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: there are no errors, jquery is loaded fine coz when i add a click event to an input it works... let me update with a different example in a fiddle.. i tried all of those mentioned in the possible duplicate but it doesnt work..

Comment: what `jquery` version you are using?

Comment: 1.7... i couldnt find the jqery function that puts the random content.. so i put up a fiddle with a select box problem.. actually its a the same.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/g1sqrxg6/3/ the click event doesnt work

Comment: @AbhishekPrakash http://jsfiddle.net/g1sqrxg6/3/

Comment: As pointed out by @Roumelis, your select.chosen-select is replaced by chosen lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first function

```
$(document).on('click', ".mootoo", function() {
      alert("clicked");
});
```

should work as you can see in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88v4339g/).
So the problem is not that your div is dynamically generated.

Update:

```
$(document).on("click",".chosen-container", function() {
    alert("clicked");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1sqrxg6/7/)

Comment: i managed to put a fiddle withe select extension..
http://jsfiddle.net/g1sqrxg6/3/ its the same problem.. when the select box is clicked doesnt alert

Comment: You are using jQuery 1.63 in your fiddle. In this version .on is not supported.

Comment: You are using chosen.js. Your select is replaced with a div with class .chosen-container. Check my updated answer for a working solution.